# My java class unable to run @Scheduled cron annotation

Tags: spring-scheduled

While executing my Java application, @Scheduled cron expression is not being called? But one of the other class in the same project executes @Scheduled cron? What could be the reason?

I was expecting the both classes should execute.

Comment: Is the `@Scheduled` annotation on an spring bean's method?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is on the class method.